Create Service Report FSL does not include Technician signature (API)
I am trying to use the CreateServiceReport API call - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_code_samples_sr.htm
My code base is same as documentation with some changes as needed -
However, the Technician signature is never generated. It is always the customer's signature.
The final JSON looks like this  -
 {
    "inputs": [{
        "entityId": "0WO1l00000abcdef",
        "signatures": [{
            "data": "base 64 data",
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "name": "Customer Signature",
            "signatureType": "Customer"
        }, {
            "data": "base 64 tech signature",
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "name": "Technician Signature",
            "signatureType": "Technician"
        }],
        "templateId": "0SL2p001233443KzIfGAK"
    }]
}

I have changed some data.
Customer signature always gets printed.
If I use the tech signature as customer signature it is printed so base 64 data is correct.
The template also has the tech signature field.
Any help would be really great.!!
